# Leetcode Numbers of Good Pairs

Tags: python, pointers

Problem wants the number of pairs in an array of nums if nums[i] == nums[j] and i > j, 0 indexed. I'm sure the solution is very simple but because I just started it's still hard to spot for me. Apologizes if I did something wrong, thanks for the help.

```
Input = [1,2,3,1,1,3]
Getting output = [3]
Expected output = [4]



def numIdenticalPairs(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
            count =0
            l, r = 0, 1
            while l <= len(nums) -2: 
                if nums[l] == nums[r] and r != len(nums) -1:
                    count+=1
                    r+=1 
                elif r == len(nums) - 1:
                    l+=1
                    r = l+1
                else:
                    r+=1
            
            
            return count
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Do you not understand why expected output is 4? Or do you not know how to make your code give you that output?

Comment: Think what happens if "l" and "r" have the indices of the threes in the list. What does the if-block then?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to make my code give me that output. I guess in my head it should cycle through the array fine and update the counter for every pair but it doesn't.

Comment: I would recommend keeping a count if each number you've seen in a dictionary. Then when you see that number again, just add the count to the total. You can then do this in O(n) time.

Comment: As for your code, because of the condition you have, you don't get a chance to compare the match when `l = 2` and `r = 5`. So that match doesn't get counted.

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript solution

```
var numIdenticalPairs = function(nums) {

    let length=nums.length;
    let result = 0;

    for(i=0 ; i<length-1; i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1 ; j<length; j++)
        {
            if(nums[i] == nums[j]) 
            {
                result++;
            }
        }
    }
       
    return result;

};
```